# javascript TypeError: txt is null

Tags: javascript

i have a code in javascript

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function kk() {
            var txt = document.getElementById(<%=txt.ClientID%>);
            if (txt.value == "rd1") {
                document.getElementById("rd1").checked = true;
            }
            console.log("kk");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt" onchange="kk()" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rd1" runat="server" />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="ed2" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

but showing errors

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, I can see one oversight in the code. Instead of:

```
var txt = document.getElementById(<%=txt.ClientID%>);
```

it should be:

```
var txt = document.getElementById('<%=txt.ClientID%>');
```

In other words, the element ID retrieved from server-side must be surrounded by quotes. If the server side expression resolves to any empty string, it would be equivalent to not sending an parameter to the `document.getElementById(id_name)` function, which would result in a JS error. And if the expression resolves to a non-empty string, then the JavaScript call would treat that as the name of a JavaScript variable as opposed to a string.

Hence the resolved value of the expression must be surrounded by quotes so JavaScript treats it as a string value.

I suppose you could further improve the error checking with something like:

```
if (txt !== null && txt.value == 'rd1') {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById()` takes a string. You should write:

```
document.getElementById("<%=txt.ClientID%>");
```

With quotes.

Otherwise, the value of `txt.ClientID` will be parsed as a variable name. Since no variable by that name exists, `undefined` will be passed to `getElementById()`, and it will return `null`.